# Arguments of function passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, reflection

Without using any behaviors which will be deprecated soon, is it possible to get the arguments from a function, which itself was passed as a function?
E.g.

```
function lowerOrder(x) {
    console.log('lower order: ');
    console.log(arguments);
}
function higherOrder(fx) {
    console.log('higher order: ');
    console.log(arguments);
};

higherOrder(lowerOrder); //in Chrome I can expand these results and see an arguments object (which is null)
```

vs.

```
function lowerOrder(x) {
    console.log('lower order: ');
    console.log(arguments);
}
function higherOrder(fx) {
    console.log('higher order: ');
    console.log(arguments);
};

higherOrder(lowerOrder(4)); //higher order function is undefined
                            //lower order correctly prints 4
```

If a function like lowerOrder(4) is passed to higherOrder, is it possible to get both the name of the function that was passed and its arguments from higherOrder?

Comment: No, that's impossible. What would you want to use this for?

Comment: In your second example, `lowerOrder` is not passed to `higherOrder`. It is called and its return value is passed. `higherOrder` does not know where the value comes from (how it was computed). You could find this out with static code analysis, but not during runtime.

Comment: @Bergi I just wanted to know if it was possible.  I spent about 20 minutes trying to figure out a way and failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and the reason is simple: In the second code, you *are not passing* `lowerOrder` to `higherOrder`.

Instead, you are passing `lowerOrder`'s *return value*, which is `undefined` because it has no `return` statement.

Comment: spot on, I was too concerned no whether or not it was possible to see the forest for the trees.